# Join range of row using arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

[image]

I have a range of data on column A and B. In Column D , i have a reference for the shotID. I want to make a list for the artist involved for specific shotID.

In E2 i use this :

```
=JOIN( "," , FILTER($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A= D2))
```

then copy down to E3,E4. It works as i expected, but i want to do it using array formula. So only use single formula in E2 and that doesn't work that simple :

```
=arrayformula( JOIN( "," , FILTER($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A= D2:D4)) )
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more possibility that I learned from player0 and surprised he didn't suggest...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(A2:B&{"|",CHAR(10)},"select MAX(Col2) where Col1<>'|' group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,100)),CHAR(10),",")),"| ",0))
```

Comment: @player0  This was your idea!

Answer (score 2):

take:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(
 FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&B2:B&","&"×"&B2:B), "×"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)), " ", "×", 1), "×")), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: see my answer.  it was you I got that construction from! surprised not to see it here in your response :)

Comment: @MattKing as you know there are many options for how to solve stuff, and I don't save logs of my nice answers so it's all individual based on my feelings :). also, there are these lurking creepy mods that do not have better things to do and they check&delete my answers if they are exact duplicates or a very similar one

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
={unique(A2:A),arrayformula(transpose(substitute(trim(query(if(A2:A<>transpose(unique(A2:A)),,B2:B),,9^9))," ",", ")))}
```

[image]